# How to solve this logical expression?

Tags: c

Please tell how to solve it by associativity and precedence:

```
   #include<stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
       int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
       m=++i||+j&&++k;
       printf("%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: @Eugene Sh. it compiles and gives the result in the answer below. `+j` is valid syntax.

Comment: It is, but why? A typo?

Comment: its ++j.it write by mistake.sory

Comment: Why didn't you copy and paste the *actual code* instead of typing it up by hand and making mistakes in the process ?

Comment: @Paul R. actually I write this program from book so this happen.

Comment: Solve it with brackets and by splitting up complex expressions into simpler ones.  Code like this is just rubbish and should never be seen outside academia.

Comment: @Jayant: OK - well it doesn't make any difference to the answer in this instance, but please be more careful in future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `||` and `&&` force left to right operation.  Both fully evaluate their LHS operand and apply any side effects before evaluating the RHS.  Both *short-circuit*; if the result of the expression can be determined from the LHS, the RHS is not evaluated at all.

For `||`, if the LHS evaluates to a non-zero value, then the RHS is not evaluated (`true OR x` is always `true`).

For `&&`, if the LHS evaluates to a zero value, then the RHS is not evaluated (`false AND x` is always `false`).

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, which has higher precedence than assignment, so the expression is *parsed* as

```
m = (++i || (++j && ++k ))
```

and *evaluated* as follows:

1. `++i` is evaluated first (`||` forces left-to-right evaluation) and the side effect of incrementing `i` is applied;
2. Since `i` is initially `-3`, `++i` evaluates to `-2`;
3. Since `++i` evaluates to a non-zero value, the RHS expression `++j && ++k` is not evaluated at all<sup>1</sup>;
4. The result of an operation involving `||` or `&&` is a boolean value (either `0` or `1`) - since `++i` is non-zero, `++i || ++j && ++k` evaluates to 1;
5. `1` is assigned to `m`.

So, by the time all of this is done, the following are true:

```
i == -2
j == 2  // unchanged
k == 0  // unchanged
m == 1
```

---

<sup>1.  If `++i` had evaluated to `0`, then `++j && ++k` would have been evaluated by evaluating `++j` first, and if the result was non-zero, evaluating `++k`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`++i` increments the value of `i` from -3 to -2, which is true, so the remaining expression is not evaluated, and the result of the expression is true (1). Hence:

```
i = -2, j = 2, k = 0, m = 1
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/TLDuqw)

Comment: but ,(m=++i||+j&&++k;) contain && (AND) operator which having higher precedence than  || (OR ) operator ,so how can we 1st solve OR operator?

Comment: The precedence is only telling that it can be rewritten as `m=++i || (+j&&++k);`. Which is still making the answer valid.

Comment: @Jayant look up "shortcut operators".

Comment: @WeatherVane: ITYM *short circuit* operators ?

Comment: I guess so Paul;) @Jayant the `&&` has precedence over `||` but that applies to the second and third operands: the first is still evaluated before the next pair, which won't be evaluated at all in this case.

Comment: @ Weather Vane, how can we understand that ()bracket given to which term  (++i || ++j ) &&++k; or ++i || (++j && ++k ) while finding output on paper .