# Printing different values for ++i||j++&&++k with printf vs cout

Tags: c++, increment

This code prints different values for `++i||j++&&++k` depending on whether the `printf` function or `cout` is used.  Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i = 1,j=1,k=1;
    cout<<++i||j++&&++k; 
    printf("%d", ++i||j++ && ++k);

}
```

Comment: Since you'll never, *ever* be writing code like this in a production scenario, you don't need to know the answer to this question.

Comment: This doesn't look undefined behavior like `i++ + ++i` because each variables are used only once per statements.

Comment: duplicates: [Why doesn't ++i || ++j && ++k give the expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55517958/995714), https://stackoverflow.com/q/28145152/995714, [How to solve this logical expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33924522/995714), [How to solve this logical expression? (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33924522/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `<<` operator has higher precedence than `||` operator. Therefore, the statement

```
cout<<++i||j++&&++k;
```

means

```
(cout<<++i) || j++&&++k;
```

Therefore, the value of `i` after the increment is printed.

In the other hand, the value of `++i||j++ && ++k` will be printed by

```
printf("%d", ++i||j++ && ++k);
```

Also note that the execution of `cout<<++i||j++&&++k;` may affect the result of `printf("%d", ++i||j++ && ++k);` because the `++` operator has side effects and the values of the variables aren't reset between the statements.