# Order of precedence in CPP

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 1 , y = 1, z = 1;
    cout << ( ++x || ++y && ++z ) << endl; //outputs 1;
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << z ;  //x = 2 , y = 1 , z = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

According to me, logical AND should evaluate first, followed by logical OR. However, the results seem to be contrasting my assumption. Can someone explain?

Comment: Have, you considered that `||` is short-circuit? If `a` in `a || (b && c)` is `true`, the second expression isn't evaluated whatever it contains.

Comment: But why would the concept of short circuit work, I mean, doesn't arithmetic work according to precedence rules? @Scheff'sCat

Comment: Better than "according to me" (which may or may not be correct), cite a source like: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing different values for ++i||j++&&++k with printf vs cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68103350/printing-different-values-for-ijk-with-printf-vs-cout)

Answer (score 4):

The operators `||` and `&&` are short-circuit (if not overloaded).

Hence, for `||`: if the first argument is `true`, the second is not evaluated.

For `&&`: if the first is `false`, the second is not evaluated.

If `a` in `a || (b && c)` is `true`, the second expression isn't evaluated whatever it contains.

(I set parentheses (which are actually not necessary) to emphasize what the 2nd argument of `||` is.)

Answer (score 2):

`operator&&` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator||`, that means `++x || ++y && ++z` will be interpreted as `++x || (++y && ++z)`, which doesn't mean `(++y && ++z)` gets evaluated firstly. `++x` is still evaluated firstly, it gives a non-zero value which could convert to `bool` with value `true`, then `(++y && ++z)` won't be evaluated due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing the precedence of an operator with order of evaluation. Yes, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so `++x || ++y && ++z`  is evaluated as `++x || (++y && ++z)`, but it's still evaluated from left to right.

See also [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> 6. Every value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of the built-in logical AND operator && and the built-in logical OR operator || is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument.

That is, the left argument of `||` will always be evaluated before the right argument. Thus `++x` is evaluated *first*, this yields `true` and the condition [short-circuits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), so `(++y && ++z)` isn't evaluated at all.